# Need embeded links for many images in a OneDrive folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Here's my problem, and I can't solve it.
Maybe you have a solution.

I have a OneDrive folder with lots of pictures in it.
What I need are "embedding links" from the pictures. But I don't want to create 5000 "embed links" individually.

Does anyone have a solution for me how to automate this?
I have already looked at MS Graph, but it involves a lot of work. I have no experience with it. Do you have another idea? Or a good explanation how to do this with MS Graph?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.....

One "simply" has to rearrange the structure of the OneDrive URL

For instance......

Here is how a URL must be structured for it to point to a file inside a onedrive folder.....

https://yourmicrosoftaccountname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/1stURLsegment/2ndURLsegment_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/1st_level_OneDrive_folder/2nd_level_OneDrive_folder/3rd_level_OneDrive_folder/filename.ext

Won't bother about going into any detail able how to structure the gallery in PowerApps such that it can use a dynamic list of files in a table to point to media files.